# Breaking conjunctions of the form &&& into subgoals in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

If I write in Isar something like:

```
have "(x ↔ z) ∙ R = (xa ↔ z) ∙ S" 
     "(x ↔ z) ∙ T = (xa ↔ z) ∙ Ta" 
     "(x ↔ z) ∙ q = (xa ↔ z) ∙ t"
```

I will get a subgoal:

```
(x ↔ z) ∙ R = (xa ↔ z) ∙ S &&&
(x ↔ z) ∙ T = (xa ↔ z) ∙ Ta &&&
(x ↔ z) ∙ q = (xa ↔ z) ∙ t
```

How do I split this &&& into three subgoals?

Comment: Nitpick: These are not “Isar conjunctions”, they are the meta conjunctions from Isabelle/Pure. Isar has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One usually only encounters such subgoals when one states a lemma with more than one statement, and this is nothing to worry about. It is virtually impossible for this to cause any problems during everyday use – you can just ignore it.

To elaborate: When you write something like `lemma P1 P2`, you do indeed see `P1 &&& P2` as a proof obligation. However, do not be alarmed by that: if you run *any* proof method, this meta-conjunction is immediately split and you have the two separate subgoals `P1` and `P2` even *before* that method sees the goal. So just pretend it's two separate subgoals from the beginning.

(With enough criminal energy, it is probably possible to avoid this automatic splitting, but only if you define your own proof methods.)

Comment: Well, you said ‘Such subgoals are very uncommon and I am not sure how to reproduce this.’ Seeing as you get such subgoals whenever you write ‘lemma’  with more than one statement to be shown, I would argue that they are *very* frequent and it is *very* easy to reproduce the situation the OP described.

Comment: In any case, I will try to edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As @Manuel says, the usual proof methods will automatically split the subgoals for you. In the rare cases where a method you're using doesn't do this, the `-` method will also split &&& meta-conjunctions. You might have seen this in `proof -`, it can also be `apply`-ed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The real problem of the question (I didn't insist though) was how to apply the same rewrite methods to the three subgoals. Given that as you say, they are automatically separated in subgoals...

Comment: The `+` method combinator usually works in this case: `by my_method+`. If you have other ambient goals floating around that you don't want to touch, you could also try `apply (-; my_method)`.